# How to use partials or helpers in mybatis XML mapper?

Tags: java, xml, database, mybatis, ibatis

I am using mybatis xml mapper.
Most of the queries contains same types of filters.
Is there any way to move these common filters in partial or helper as common place.

```
select id="getMaxData" resultMap="Result">
    SELECT IFNULL(MAX(data), 0) AS data
    FROM well_data WHERE result = 'foo' AND data > 0

    <if test="test1 != '' ">
        AND test1 = #{test1}
    </if>
    <if test="test2 != '' ">
        AND test2 = #{test2}
    </if>
    <if test="test3 != '' ">
        AND test3 = #{test3}
    </if>
</select>

select id="getAverageData" resultMap="Result">
    SELECT IFNULL(AVG(data), 0) AS data
    FROM well_data WHERE result = 'foo' AND data > 0

    <if test="test1 != '' ">
        AND test1 = #{test1}
    </if>
    <if test="test2 != '' ">
        AND test2 = #{test2}
    </if>
    <if test="test3 != '' ">
        AND test3 = #{test3}
    </if>
</select>
```

Instead of using same filters every time is there any way to put this in common partial like:

```
common partial
    <if test="test1 != '' ">
        AND test1 = #{test1}
    </if>
    <if test="test2 != '' ">
        AND test2 = #{test2}
    </if>
    <if test="test3 != '' ">
        AND test3 = #{test3}
    </if>
```

then using this common partial every time I need it

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `<include/>`:

```
<sql id="common-constraints">
    <if test="test1 != '' ">
        AND test1 = #{test1}
    </if>
    <if test="test2 != '' ">
        AND test2 = #{test2}
    </if>
    <if test="test3 != '' ">
        AND test3 = #{test3}
    </if>
</sql>
```

And then:

```
<select id="getMaxData" resultMap="Result">
    SELECT IFNULL(MAX(data), 0) AS data
    FROM well_data WHERE result = 'foo' AND data > 0
    <include refid="common-constraints"/>
</select>
```

See also [link](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html) if it doesn't work for your case.